# Export Announcements List w/ Created/Last Modified Date & User

Tags: migration

I'm migrating data from 1 MOSS 2010 site to a new one. I've been successfully able to move the data from the announcements list on the old site to the new site, however they got imported in a random order and all list items have the import date as the date created and last modified and me as the creator and last modifier.

How can I export the created/last modified date and user along with the rest of the list?

Answer (score 1):

Try the stsadm Export/Import. With this command you can export a list:

```
stsadm -o export -url "http://oldsite/path/to/list" -filename "C:\temp\list.cmp"
```

and import with

```
stsadm -o import -url "http://newsite/path/to/list" -filename "C:\temp\list.cmp"
```

Comment: This method exactly what I was asking not to get. With the import, they are, yet again, all created/last modified at the time of the import by the importing user.